# How can I set locale on a TeamCity agent running on a mac?

Tags: console, teamcity

I have a TeamCity agent running on a mac. The server is in docker and is whatever current version they are set at.

when I do `pod install` I get the following error

```
[11:50:13][Step 2/3]     WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
[11:50:13][Step 2/3]     Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:
[11:50:13][Step 2/3] 
[11:50:13][Step 2/3]     export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

If I run `locale` in the build step I see

```
[11:50:11][Step 2/3] LANG=
[11:50:11][Step 2/3] LC_COLLATE="C"
[11:50:11][Step 2/3] LC_CTYPE="C"
[11:50:11][Step 2/3] LC_MESSAGES="C"
[11:50:11][Step 2/3] LC_MONETARY="C"
[11:50:11][Step 2/3] LC_NUMERIC="C"
[11:50:11][Step 2/3] LC_TIME="C"
[11:50:11][Step 2/3] LC_ALL=
```

If I do the same when logged in as the agent user in a normal bash console I see

```
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How can I set the LANG etc properties in the console the TeamCity agent runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was the Docker bound server.

I created a docker file `Dockerfile-server`

```
FROM 'jetbrains/teamcity-server'

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install locales -y  
RUN locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8  
ENV LANG en_GB.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_GB:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_GB.UTF-8
```

and referenced it in my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:  
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-server
    volumes:
    - '/Users/teamcity/Desktop/data:/data/teamcity_server/datadir'
    - '/Users/teamcity/Desktop/logs:/data/teamcity/logs'
    ports:
      - 8111:8111
    environment:
      - TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS="-Xmx750m"
```

and I see the results

```
[13:25:26][Step 2/3] LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
[13:25:26][Step 2/3] LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
[13:25:26][Step 2/3] LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
[13:25:26][Step 2/3] LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
[13:25:26][Step 2/3] LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
[13:25:26][Step 2/3] LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
[13:25:26][Step 2/3] LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
[13:25:26][Step 2/3] LC_ALL=
```

excelent